# Cypher function call changes return value depending of number of results

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I'm using a query to execute lucene search over a property in a Neo4j database. As I want to query by several different strings I've come with the following query

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes('descs', 'abc') YIELD node
with collect(node) as matches1
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes('descs', 'def') YIELD node
with matches1, collect(node) as matches2
RETURN apoc.coll.intersection(matches1,matches2) AS res
```

Query works fine sometimes but seems to behave weirdly when too many results are returned in any of the calls (still don't know the actual limit). More precisely, if any of the queries returns a big list, then the query returns just "[]". It seems to work perfectly if query returns a list with few nodes (or no nodes, which provides no results due to doing an intersection with an empty list). Is there any configurable (or non-configurable) limit on apoc.coll.intersection function or any of the other calls? Things are aggravated when using the '~' operand, as it usually returns more results. This means that similar queries will or will not work as expected depending on how many matches provides the queryNodes call.

Also, as there could be any number of words to search, is there a way to generalize this kind of query? queryNodes seems to not work well with spaces inside the text to search. Regex could be an option but it doesn't really work well when dealing with accents and/or searching for multiple words in any given order.

Comment: For the sake of reproducing this, for one of your queries where you run into problems, can you give the count of nodes returned by each of the two fulltext index lookups? Also can you confirm your version of Neo4j, APOC, and your configured heap and pagecache in neo4j.conf?

Comment: Happens with return count of 259 and 744. Neo4j version is 3.5.14, Apoc is 3.5.0.5. No heap or pagecache parameters are provided in neo4j.conf

Comment: Also updated node display to 1000 with ":config initialNodeDisplay: 1000" just in case it had something to do with that

Comment: For the second part of the question, I've found that lucene tends to ignore things if not explicitly told so. Correct syntax to generalize the query is something in the lines of 
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes('descs', '+*abc* +*cdr*') YIELD node,score